# Retrieve posts in custom post type and specific taxonomies

Tags: wp-query, query, get-posts

I'm struggling with what seems like should be so simple looking at [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Taxonomy_Parameters).

I have a custom post type, let's call it 'portfolio'.

A custom taxonomy for that, let's call it 'clients'.

I can use get_posts() to list all 'portfolio' items but also need the ability to pass in / filter by the 'clients' taxonomy slugs or display all. ("acme,ibm,tbs" - or null/blank)

I've torn apart my sample code so many times that I don't remember anymore what I haven't tried.

Maybe I should instead go with WP_Query()? Sorry for probably such a stupid question, I just can't interpret the example apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `get_posts()` and `wp_query()` should be able to do this by passing the `tax_query` array into them.

Example:

```
$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'clients',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'acme' )
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$posts = get_posts( $query );
```

Comment: Ah-ha! I only had one array in the tax_query, not the array of arrays. Thank you so much, my head was about to fall off...